# VBA: Run-time error 91 - problem fixing one line

Tags: excel, vba

Forgive the code, still learning VBA so doing things the long way.

This macro ran with no problems yesterday, but today it's giving me an error 91 on a line:

```
HiddenCell7.Value = "=CELL(""address""," & TodaysDateP7.Address(External:=True) & ")"
```

I can't figure out what the issue is.

Code below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim Date0 As Date
Dim Date1 As Date
Dim Date2 As Date
Dim Date3 As Date
Dim Date4 As Date
Dim Date5 As Date
Dim Date6 As Date

Dim TodaysDateP1 As Range
Dim TodaysDateP2 As Range
Dim TodaysDateP3 As Range
Dim TodaysDateP4 As Range
Dim TodaysDateP5 As Range
Dim TodaysDateP6 As Range
Dim TodaysDateP7 As Range

Dim HiddenCell1 As Range
Dim HiddenCell2 As Range
Dim HiddenCell3 As Range
Dim HiddenCell4 As Range
Dim HiddenCell5 As Range
Dim HiddenCell6 As Range
Dim HiddenCell7 As Range

Date0 = Date
Date1 = DateAdd("d", 1, Date)
Date2 = DateAdd("d", 2, Date)
Date3 = DateAdd("d", 3, Date)
Date4 = DateAdd("d", 4, Date)
Date5 = DateAdd("d", 5, Date)
Date6 = DateAdd("d", 6, Date)

Set TodaysDateP1 = Range("April2020").Find(Date0)
Set TodaysDateP2 = Range("April2020").Find(Date1)
Set TodaysDateP3 = Range("April2020").Find(Date2)
Set TodaysDateP4 = Range("April2020").Find(Date3)
Set TodaysDateP5 = Range("April2020").Find(Date4)
Set TodaysDateP6 = Range("April2020").Find(Date5)
Set TodaysDateP7 = Range("April2020").Find(Date6)

Set HiddenCell1 = Sheets("W").Range("C15")
Set HiddenCell2 = Sheets("W").Range("H15")
Set HiddenCell3 = Sheets("W").Range("M15")
Set HiddenCell4 = Sheets("W").Range("R15")
Set HiddenCell5 = Sheets("W").Range("C33")
Set HiddenCell6 = Sheets("W").Range("H33")
Set HiddenCell7 = Sheets("W").Range("M33")

HiddenCell1.Value = "=CELL(""address""," & TodaysDateP1.Address(External:=True) & ")"
HiddenCell2.Value = "=CELL(""address""," & TodaysDateP2.Address(External:=True) & ")"
HiddenCell3.Value = "=CELL(""address""," & TodaysDateP3.Address(External:=True) & ")"
HiddenCell4.Value = "=CELL(""address""," & TodaysDateP4.Address(External:=True) & ")"
HiddenCell5.Value = "=CELL(""address""," & TodaysDateP5.Address(External:=True) & ")"
HiddenCell6.Value = "=CELL(""address""," & TodaysDateP6.Address(External:=True) & ")"
HiddenCell7.Value = "=CELL(""address""," & TodaysDateP7.Address(External:=True) & ")"

End Sub
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: That means that the `Find` in `Set TodaysDateP7 = Range("April2020").Find(Date6)` was not successful, i.e. `Date6` wasn't found in that range.

Comment: As @BigBen said, and thus, `TodaysDateP7` is `Nothing`. Which has no `Address` property.

Comment: Thank you all! The issue was in the source dataset.